# Difference between cluster and clusterdata in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I would like to know the difference between `cluster` and `clusterdata` algorithms in MatLab. 
The reason is that I have this code with the same options

```
% First method
y = pdist(X, 'chebyshev');
z = linkage(y, 'single');
cl = cluster(z, 'maxclust', 10);
figure;
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3), 10, cl)

% second method
H =  clusterdata(X,'linkage', 'single', 'distance', 'chebyshev', 'maxclust',10);
figure;
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3), 10, H)
```

I have attached the two figures from these two methods. I don't understand why they have different outputs.

[image: from cluster]

[image: from Clusterdata]

Answer (score 0):

The difference probably stem from the fact that you are not using the same distance parameter for both (`'jaccard'` in `pdist` vs`'chebyshev'` in `clusterdata`).

`clusterdata`  is a wraper around the `pdist`, `linker`, and `cluster` functions (you can check that by yourself by opening their source code in the editor with `right clic` -> `open selection`).

If you give the same parameters, you will get the same results.

Comment: This is just a mistake I made in writing the code here. I am using the same distance parameter. Both of them are Chebyshev. I'll update the question.